# How to remove video background with ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

Is there a way in ffmpeg-python to remove a single colored green screen background and to replace it with another video?

So I have a video "test.mp4". It is basically a man talking in front of a green screen. I would like to add multiple background videos. One from second 0-5 the next from second 5-15 and so on.

The green screen is only one color so no shadows or anything else just one single green color. Is there a way to remove the green screen in ffmpeg-python or an other python library?

Comment: Try `colorkey` filter. [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) has the exact usage of yours.

Comment: Thank you but how can I use that in python?

Comment: I run it with `subprocess.run` unless I need it to be interactive, in which case I'd use `subprocess.Popen`.